# The same Test Suite is passed on IDEA, but fails when running on Teamcity

Tags: selenium-webdriver, teamcity

Need a help. I have the same test suite. I have run this test suite in IDEA on my local machine. And the tests are passed. Then I run this test suite in TeamCity. The tests are failed with the next stack trace:

```
======= Failed test run #1 ==========
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
(Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 18 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '31c43c8', time: '2016-08-02 21:57:56 -0700'
System info: host: 'build', ip: '175.35.15.235', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf), userDataDir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\scoped_dir948_4499}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=54.0.2840.71, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: e69e7517d0cc60ff138519603c9efe99
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 
element not visible
(Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 18 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '31c43c8', time: '2016-08-02 21:57:56 -0700'
System info: host: 'build', ip: '175.35.15.235', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf), userDataDir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\scoped_dir948_4499}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=54.0.2840.71, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: e69e7517d0cc60ff138519603c9efe99
at com.automation.webdriver.testStoryReportsNavigation.policiesWithPremium(testStoryReportsNavigation.java:122)
```

122 line of code like this:
driver.findElement (By.xpath ( "// * [@ id = \" 0 \ "]")) click (); 
(No matter for xpath looking for, or id - in TeamCity the same result)

In what may be the cause of this error?
Tests are run with agent on the same machine that serves TeamCity.

There is a code:

```
package com.automation.webdriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.CaptureScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import pageObjects.homePage;
import utility.Constant;
import utility.ExcelUtils;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class testStoryReportsNavigation {

public WebDriver driver;
private int storyNumber;
private String storyDescription;


@Factory(dataProvider = "dataMethod", dataProviderClass = dataProvider.class)
public testStoryReportsNavigation(int storyNumber, String storyDescription) {
    this.storyNumber = storyNumber;
    this.storyDescription = storyDescription;
}

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeClass() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty(Constant.chromeDriver,Constant.chromeDriverPath);
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constant.File_userData,"Users");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get(Constant.devUrl + Constant.loginPage);

    WebDriverWait waitLoginPage = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    waitLoginPage.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Log in Milliman"));

    if (driver.findElements(By.className("glimpse-icon")).size()!=0) {
        driver.get(Constant.devUrl + Constant.glimpseSettings);
        driver.findElement(By.id("buttonTurnGlimpseOff")).click();
        driver.getPageSource().contains("Glimpse cookie set 'Off'");
        driver.get(Constant.devUrl + Constant.loginPage);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Glimpse disabled");
    }

    WebDriverWait waitLoginPageAgain = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    waitLoginPageAgain.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Log in Milliman"));

    WebElement eMail = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
    eMail.sendKeys(ExcelUtils.getCellData(1, 1));

    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("Password"));
    password.sendKeys(ExcelUtils.getCellData(1, 2));
    password.submit();

    //Check that Grid View appears after user login:
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains(Constant.gridView));

    System.out.println("Login Successful");

    //Navigate to Story
    System.out.println("Navigating to " + Constant.devUrl + Constant.storyPage + storyNumber + "(" + storyDescription + ")");
    driver.get(Constant.devUrl + Constant.storyPage + storyNumber);
    WebDriverWait waitLogout = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    waitLogout.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("FiltersShortSummaryBlock")));
    //Check that story loaded
    driver.findElement(By.className("FiltersShortSummaryBlock")).click();
    WebDriverWait waitUrButton = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    waitUrButton.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("UpdateResults")));
    //Select Data Source value
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"PanelGeneral\"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/button")).click();
    WebDriverWait waitDataSource = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    waitDataSource.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Market Basket')]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Market Basket')]")).click();
    //Select Primary Carrier value
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"PanelGeneral\"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/button")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[60]/ul/li[2]/label")).click();

    //Select Secondary Carriers value
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"PanelGeneral\"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/button")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[14]/div/ul/li[1]/a/span[2]")).click();

    //Click Update Results button
    WebDriverWait waitButton = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    waitButton.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("UpdateResults")));
    WebElement updateResults = driver.findElement(By.id("UpdateResults"));
    updateResults.click();
    //Check that Results were updated
    WebDriverWait waitUpdateResults = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    waitUpdateResults.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("storyUnsaved")));
}

@Test (priority = 11)
public void policiesWithPremium() throws Exception {
    //Generate report #0 and check that it was generated
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"0\"]")).click();
    //Check that report #0 was generated
    WebDriverWait waitReportZero = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
    waitReportZero.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("RiskWithPremiumForm")));
}
```

Comment: Try repeating the visibility check for this element that you are doing for waitReportZero element just beneath it. Also you should not mix implicit and explicit timeouts. You will run into problems with wait times.

Comment: Did you get the resolution of this.